# Dimension distinct count SSAS within the context of other dimensions

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, olap

I have this MDX;

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].DistinctOrderCount<br/>
AS 
  DistinctCount([Order].[Order Id].[Order Id] - [Order].[Order Id].[1]),<br/>
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;-#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Fact Sales';
```

I am trying to do a distinct of orders (except Order Id=1) within the context of other dimensions in my fact table. For example, distinct order count by dim customers, dim city, dim state etc. but I am not able to achieve this. When I view my measure on a report, I get distinct count of order dimension which is 21 being displayed on all rows of customers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I solved this and I am happy with the results. Hope this may help others. The idea is, create a cube measure with aggregation type ***Distinct Count*** and set column binding on the column you want distinct count on. Then use the below MDX to filter out the dummy Order Id's from your distinct count.

```
create member currentcube.[Measures].OrderCount<br/>
as<br/>
distinctcount
(

    existing 
    CROSSJOIN
             (
              Except([Orders].[Order Id].[Order Id], [Orders].[Order Id].&[1]), 
              [Measures].[Order Count]
             )

),<br/>
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;-#,##0", 
VISIBLE = 1, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP='Order Count';
```

Comment: @whytheq, your input was highly valuable and because of that I was able to connect the dots and draft the solution. Thanks, pleasure working with you.